# Correct MsTest version to use in App.Config with Specflow v1.9

Tags: mstest

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate on one PC and...
Visual Studio 2012 Premium on another PC.

In order to run Specflow v1.9 correctly which MsTest version should I specify in the App.Config file:

- MsTest
- MsTest.2010
  or
- MsTest.2012

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="specFlow" type="TechTalk.SpecFlow.Configuration.ConfigurationSectionHandler, TechTalk.SpecFlow" />
  </configSections>
  <specFlow>
    <unitTestProvider name="MsTest.2010" />
  </specFlow>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that having VS Test Agent and VS Test Controller running were causing my usual behaviour.

I settled on:

```
<unitTestProvider name="MsTest" />
```